# Can not resolve "May expose internal representation by returning reference to mutable object"

Tags: java, sonarqube

SonarQube keeps reporting an issue for rule "may expose internal representation by returning reference to mutable object".

I fixed it based on a [guide of the Carnegie Mellon University](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/OBJ05-J.+Do+not+return+references+to+private+mutable+class+members), but SonarQube still raises this issue:

```
public Date getDatime(){
    return (Date)this.datime.clone();//IJTI-316
    // .getDatime() may expose internal representation by returning *.datime
}
```

How can I resolve / avoid this issue?

Comment: Which version of SonarQube do you use? Which plugins have you installed for Java analysis?

Comment: In eclipse, I'm using SonarLint. And SonarQube version 6.1

Answer (score 3):

The clone operation does a shallow copy, meaning that most of the Date's instance variables are shared between both instances. To fully solve the error you need to make an entirely new object in the regular sense.

Maybe:

```
return new Date(this.datime.getTime());
```

Comment: How about set method: this.datime = new Date(datime.getTime());
It still keep this issue!

Comment: Of course it does, you're simply replacing your internal representation with another internal representation and returning that.